# Who is Rabbi Shimeon who discusses with Rabbi Yochanan in Gemara

Tags: rabbis, maseches-kiddushin, amoroim

Gemara [Kiddushin 66b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.66b.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> אמר ליה רבי שמעון לרבי יוחנן כללא הוא דכל מקום שיש קידושין ואין עבירה הולד הולך אחר הזכר
>
> Rabbi Shimeon said to Rabbi Yochanan, it is a general principle!?

I assume that it's not The Tana Rabbi Shimeon. It is plausible that it is Rabbi Shimeon Ben Lakish. But I never did seen that the Talmud calls Rabbi Shimeon Ben Lakish just Rabbi Shimeon. Is there sources discussing who is this Rabbi Shimeon?

Despite that Rabbi Yochanan cites ofen Rabbi Shimeon Ben Yochai, I think that Rabbi Shimeon not asked to Rabbi Yochanan questions on Mishnayot.

Comment: The Tanna R’ Shimon was a contemporary of R’ Meir’s, right? That puts him two generations before R’ Yehudah HaNasi, who in turn was two generations before R’ Yochanan. Rebbi and R’ Yochanan didn’t overlap for very long; I’d say that it’s impossible that this Gemara refers to R’ Shimon the Tanna.

Comment: But RS asked RY a question on the Mishna??

Answer (score 9):

The edition of Shas at [HebrewBooks.org](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=66b&format=pdf) contains a footnote suggesting that it is indeed R. Shimon b. Lakish.

It notes that there are manuscripts with this reading, as well as the parallel text in the [Talmud Yerushalmi](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Kiddushin.40a.2?lang=bi).

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to the answer of @Joel K I searched in manuscripts of the Sifria Leumit.

See in [Manuscript Vatican Apostolica Hebr 110-111](http://web.nli.org.il/sites/NLI/Hebrew/collections/jewish-collection/Talmud/Pages/default.aspx?IsByManuscript=False&Im_Ms=358&Fr_Co=4&Fr_Tr=30&Pe_code=069&Mi_code=01&Li_code=-1) that the text is Amar leih Rabbi Shimeon Ben Lakish (Left column fourth line)